# How to trigger the Dropbox option to upload when select file

Tags: android, xamarin, dropbox-api

How can we trigger the Dropbox option  to upload when select the file from my application using xamarin android? The Dropbox should be trigger if Dropbox app is installed already in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

upload to dropbox is basically sharing file of a specific type from your app to any other app that accepts this type of file. on android, this can be done through Intent and IntentFilter by setting the DataMimeType.

You can find very detailed tutorial on native android here:
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

A complete Xamarin forms example can be found here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58297/how-to-handle-android-intentfilter-to-open-app-with-specific-file-types

hope this helps!